# How ensure authentication with AJAX functions? Currently using Java Bean for authentication

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, authentication

I have a web app that uses a Java Bean for login functions right now and all of the JSP pages check the Bean to make sure the user is logged in. I am also introducing some AJAX functionality now with servlets and I see that of course those exchanges don't check authentication. I'm wondering how I should handle this. For example, I don't want someone to be able to logout, hit back button, then submit something with the AJAX functions successfully.

I can't access the bean from the servlet to check the login (totally wrong context and static vs non-static). I guess I could set a flag with the user entry in the database table denoting logged in or not. Then I can detect timeout logoffs and update the flag as well. But that way would require extra database accesses every time something is done. It would duplicate functionality in some way, but I guess I could perhaps use that just for the AJAX stuff. One difference with that would be the user would not be able to be logged in on multiple places at once as currently.

How is this kind of thing normally done? 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use session to store that flag instead of the database, and when the user logs out you should remove that flag and destroy the session. In login method

`HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
 session.setAttribute("loggedIn",true)`

And in your AJAX code

`if(eq.getSession(true).getAttribute("loggedIn")==true)
    doWork();
else
    error("not logged in");`

The webcontainer will handle timeouts for you, keep track of each user and his session, and so on.

But I would recommend that you use a standard for managing authntication

Comment: Thanks. This will work for checking a user is authenticated from both JSPs and servlets?

Comment: Yes, it can do the job for both JSP and and Ajax requests. Remember that JSP is a special type of servlets. Ajax and JSP will both share the same session, so whatever you store in the session is available to both of them.

Comment: Ok, excellent. "Ajax and JSP will both share the same session" - that is what I was curious about (yes JSP is type of servlet but didn't know they would have access to same session info). 

"But I would recommend that you use a standard for managing authntication" - could you explain this more? Have some examples of what I should look for?

Comment: Check the [offical JEE Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbwy.html)

Comment: @mikato Also check Tomcat [Relam Configuaration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/realm-howto.html)

Comment: Thanks. I have just been looking into Apache Shiro http://shiro.apache.org/ . I was hoping to keep my app container-agnostic so that I don't need to rework authentication in the app if I changed from Tomcat to something else. I hope I can adopt it somewhat easily and it seems to have great usability and flexibility from a quick look. Do you know of it?